# How to resolve error this bitbake build error: undefined reference to symbol 'ERR_reason_error_string@@OPENSSL_1_1_0'

Tags: cmake, yocto, bitbake

I am trying to integrate [do-client](https://github.com/microsoft/do-client) into my yocto image targeting raspberrypi4.

My recipe file:

```
LICENSE = "CLOSED"

DO_SRC_URI ?= "gitsm://github.com/microsoft/do-client;branch=main"
SRC_URI = "${DO_SRC_URI}"
SRCREV = "cd2eaadc0755c93bb31234a19a4577aced9845e5"

python () {
    src_uri = d.getVar('DO_SRC_URI')
    if src_uri.startswith('git'):
        d.setVar('PV', '1.0+git' + d.getVar('SRCPV'))
        d.setVar('S', d.getVar('WORKDIR') + "/git")
    elif src_uri.startswith('file'):
        d.setVar('S',  d.getVar('WORKDIR') + "/do-client")
}

DEPENDS = "boost cpprest libproxy msft-gsl"

inherit cmake

BUILD_TYPE ?= "Debug"
EXTRA_OECMAKE += "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=${BUILD_TYPE}"
# Don't build DO tests.
EXTRA_OECMAKE += "-DDO_BUILD_TESTS=OFF"
# Specify build is for deliveryoptimization-agent
EXTRA_OECMAKE += "-DDO_INCLUDE_AGENT=ON"


# cpprest installs its config.cmake file in a non-standard location.
# Tell cmake where to find it.
EXTRA_OECMAKE += "-Dcpprestsdk_DIR=${WORKDIR}/recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/cmake"
BBCLASSEXTEND = "native nativesdk"
```

The error message:

```
/build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/deliveryoptimization-agent/1.0+gitAUTOINC+cd2eaadc07-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-g++  -mthumb -mfpu=neon-vfpv4 -mfloat-abi=hard -mcpu=cortex-a7 -fstack-protector-strong  -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Wformat-security -Werror=format-security  --sysroot=/build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/deliveryoptimization-agent/1.0+gitAUTOINC+cd2eaadc07-r0/recipe-sysroot  -O2 -pipe -g -feliminate-unused-debug-types -fmacro-prefix-map=/build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/deliveryoptimization-agent/1.0+gitAUTOINC+cd2eaadc07-r0=/usr/src/debug/deliveryoptimization-agent/1.0+gitAUTOINC+cd2eaadc07-r0                      -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/deliveryoptimization-agent/1.0+gitAUTOINC+cd2eaadc07-r0=/usr/src/debug/deliveryoptimization-agent/1.0+gitAUTOINC+cd2eaadc07-r0                      -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/deliveryoptimization-agent/1.0+gitAUTOINC+cd2eaadc07-r0/recipe-sysroot=                      -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/deliveryoptimization-agent/1.0+gitAUTOINC+cd2eaadc07-r0/recipe-sysroot-native=  -fvisibility-inlines-hidden  -mthumb -mfpu=neon-vfpv4 -mfloat-abi=hard -mcpu=cortex-a7 -fstack-protector-strong  -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Wformat-security -Werror=format-security  --sysroot=/build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/deliveryoptimization-agent/1.0+gitAUTOINC+cd2eaadc07-r0/recipe-sysroot -Wall -fPIE -pie -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fmerge-all-constants -Wno-noexcept-type -g -DDEBUG  -mthumb -mfpu=neon-vfpv4 -mfloat-abi=hard -mcpu=cortex-a7 -fstack-protector-strong  -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Wformat-security -Werror=format-security  --sysroot=/build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/deliveryoptimization-agent/1.0+gitAUTOINC+cd2eaadc07-r0/recipe-sysroot  -O2 -pipe -g -feliminate-unused-debug-types -fmacro-prefix-map=/build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/deliveryoptimization-agent/1.0+gitAUTOINC+cd2eaadc07-r0=/usr/src/debug/deliveryoptimization-agent/1.0+gitAUTOINC+cd2eaadc07-r0                      -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/deliveryoptimization-agent/1.0+gitAUTOINC+cd2eaadc07-r0=/usr/src/debug/deliveryoptimization-agent/1.0+gitAUTOINC+cd2eaadc07-r0                      -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/deliveryoptimization-agent/1.0+gitAUTOINC+cd2eaadc07-r0/recipe-sysroot=                      -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/deliveryoptimization-agent/1.0+gitAUTOINC+cd2eaadc07-r0/recipe-sysroot-native=  -fvisibility-inlines-hidden  -mthumb -mfpu=neon-vfpv4 -mfloat-abi=hard -mcpu=cortex-a7 -fstack-protector-strong  -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Wformat-security -Werror=format-security  --sysroot=/build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/deliveryoptimization-agent/1.0+gitAUTOINC+cd2eaadc07-r0/recipe-sysroot -Wl,-O1 -Wl,--hash-style=gnu -Wl,--as-needed -fstack-protector-strong -Wl,-z,relro,-z,now -Wl,-O1 -Wl,--hash-style=gnu -Wl,--as-needed -fstack-protector-strong -Wl,-z,relro,-z,now -pie -z relro -z now client-lite/CMakeFiles/deliveryoptimization-agent.dir/src/exe/docs.cpp.o  -o client-lite/deliveryoptimization-agent  client-lite/common/lib-doversion/libdoversion.a  client-lite/libdocs_common.a  /build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/deliveryoptimization-agent/1.0+gitAUTOINC+cd2eaadc07-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libcpprest.so.2.10  /build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/deliveryoptimization-agent/1.0+gitAUTOINC+cd2eaadc07-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libboost_random.so.1.72.0  /build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/deliveryoptimization-agent/1.0+gitAUTOINC+cd2eaadc07-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libboost_system.so.1.72.0  /build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/deliveryoptimization-agent/1.0+gitAUTOINC+cd2eaadc07-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libboost_thread.so.1.72.0  /build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/deliveryoptimization-agent/1.0+gitAUTOINC+cd2eaadc07-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libboost_filesystem.so.1.72.0  /build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/deliveryoptimization-agent/1.0+gitAUTOINC+cd2eaadc07-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libboost_chrono.so.1.72.0  /build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/deliveryoptimization-agent/1.0+gitAUTOINC+cd2eaadc07-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libboost_atomic.so.1.72.0  /build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/deliveryoptimization-agent/1.0+gitAUTOINC+cd2eaadc07-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libboost_date_time.so.1.72.0  /build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/deliveryoptimization-agent/1.0+gitAUTOINC+cd2eaadc07-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libboost_regex.so.1.72.0  /build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/deliveryoptimization-agent/1.0+gitAUTOINC+cd2eaadc07-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libboost_log.so.1.72.0  /build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/deliveryoptimization-agent/1.0+gitAUTOINC+cd2eaadc07-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libproxy.so  /build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/deliveryoptimization-agent/1.0+gitAUTOINC+cd2eaadc07-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libboost_thread.so.1.72.0  -lpthread  /build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/deliveryoptimization-agent/1.0+gitAUTOINC+cd2eaadc07-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libboost_filesystem.so.1.72.0  /build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/deliveryoptimization-agent/1.0+gitAUTOINC+cd2eaadc07-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libboost_chrono.so.1.72.0  /build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/deliveryoptimization-agent/1.0+gitAUTOINC+cd2eaadc07-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libboost_atomic.so.1.72.0  /build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/deliveryoptimization-agent/1.0+gitAUTOINC+cd2eaadc07-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libboost_date_time.so.1.72.0  /build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/deliveryoptimization-agent/1.0+gitAUTOINC+cd2eaadc07-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libboost_regex.so.1.72.0 && :
| /build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/deliveryoptimization-agent/1.0+gitAUTOINC+cd2eaadc07-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/../../libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/9.3.0/ld: client-lite/CMakeFiles/deliveryoptimization-agent.dir/src/exe/docs.cpp.o: undefined reference to symbol 'ERR_reason_error_string@@OPENSSL_1_1_0'
| /build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/deliveryoptimization-agent/1.0+gitAUTOINC+cd2eaadc07-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/../../libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/9.3.0/ld: /build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/deliveryoptimization-agent/1.0+gitAUTOINC+cd2eaadc07-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
| collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
| ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
| WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
| ERROR: Execution of '/build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/deliveryoptimization-agent/1.0+gitAUTOINC+cd2eaadc07-r0/temp/run.do_compile.9472' failed with exit code 1
ERROR: Task (/work/meta-azure-device-update/recipes-azure-device-update/deliveryoptimization-agent/deliveryoptimization-agent_git.bb:do_compile) failed with exit code '1'
```

My best guess from previous research is that i need to pass -lcrypto as an argument to the compiler but i'm not sure how to do that.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you haven't added `openssl` to `DEPENDS`.

Comment: Hi Oleksandr, I included openssl to the dependencies and ran `bitbake -c cleanall deliveryoptimization-agent`and `bitbake deliveryoptimization-agent` but that did not resolve the issue.

Comment: wrong openssl version then?

Comment: poky provides a recipe for openssl1.1.1l . can i specify a dependency version, and if i can, do i need a separate openssl recipe for that?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by another seemingly unrelated package which had errors  on the first run but would build fine when restarting the build process. Fixing that problem also resolved this issue.